# Scraping Table using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the table below using python. Tried pulling html tags to find the element **id_dt1_NGY00** and so on but cannot find it once the page is populated so someone told me use Selenium and did manage to scrape some data.

https://www.insidefutures.com/markets/data.php?page=quote&sym=ng&x=13&y=8

The numbers are updated every 10 minutes so this website is dynamic. Used the following code below but it is printing out everything in a linear format rather than in a format that can be tabular as rows and columns. Included below are two sections of sample output

```
Contract
Last  
Change
Open
High  
Low
Volume
Prev. Stl.
Time
Links
```

May '21 (NGK21)

```
2.550s
+0.006
2.550
2.550
2.550
1
2.544
05/21/18
Q / C / O
```

Jun '21 (NGM21)

```
2.576s
+0.006
0.000
2.576
2.576
0
2.570
05/21/18
Q / C / O
```

Code below
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= "C:\Users\siddk\PycharmProjects\WebSraping\venv\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://www.insidefutures.com/markets/data.php?page=quote&sym=ng&x=14&y=16")

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

th_tags = soup.find_all('tr')
for th in th_tags:
       print (th.get_text())

I want to extract this data in Panda and analyze averages etc on daily basis. Please help. I have exhausted my strength on doing this myself with multiple iterations to code.

Comment: You didn't include any code

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below script to get the tabular data. It is necessary to find the [right url](https://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php?page=quote&sym=ng&x=13&y=8&domain=if&display_ice=1&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0) which contains the same table but does not get generated dynamically so that you can do your operation without using any browser simulator.

Give it a go:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php?page=quote&sym=ng&x=13&y=8&domain=if&display_ice=1&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for tr in soup.find(class_="bcQuoteTable").find_all("tr"):
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in tr.find_all(["th","td"])]
    print(data)
```

Rusults are like:

```
['Contract', 'Last', 'Change', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Volume', 'Prev. Stl.', 'Time', 'Links']
['Cash (NGY00)', '2.770s', '+0.010', '0.000', '2.770', '2.770', '0', '2.760', '05/21/18', 'Q/C/O']
["Jun \\'18 (NGM18)", '2.901', '-0.007', '2.902', '2.903', '2.899', '138', '2.908', '17:11', 'Q/C/O']
["Jul \\'18 (NGN18)", '2.927', '-0.009', '2.928', '2.930', '2.926', '91', '2.936', '17:11', 'Q/C/O']
["Aug \\'18 (NGQ18)", '2.944', '-0.008', '2.945', '2.947', '2.944', '42', '2.952', '17:10', 'Q/C/O']
```

Comment: Hello Sim - Appreciate it very much and the code is working. Two questions. 1>Was there anything different that struck you to find an alternate website for same data? 2> Do I assume that it is not at all possible to scrape data from insidefutures.com? If yes, could you find me in the direction on why? I am new to Python so wanted to know some nitty gritty else I will waste my time in future on scraping websites that may be futile.

Comment: I would appreciate a response to my question above.

Comment: It is obviously possible to scrape the data from your mentioned site. In that case you need to use any browser simulator like selenium which can deal with javascript encrypted sites cause you know the data in that site are generated dynamically which requests library can't handle. I found that url I've used within my scraper from chrome developper tools. You need to study first how a site does it's network activity. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sim. Do you recommend any good book that goes into detail for web scraping?

Comment: Can someone please answer my question? Sorry I am new so need a helping hand.